# Optimised FFMPEG parameters

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

How do I optimize the following to the specifications. The current one has random lags & pause while streaming.

ffmpeg -re -y -i FILENAME.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 600k -filter:v yadif -ac 1 -ar 44100 -f flv "rtmp://..."

**Video Format**

1. Maximum 720p (720 x 1280) resolution, at 30 frames per second. (or 1
   key frame every 2 seconds).
2. You must send an I-frame (keyframe) at least once every two seconds
   throughout the stream..
3. Recommended max bit rate is 4000 Kbps.
4. The accepts H264 encoded video and AAC encoded audio only.

**Advanced Settings**

5. Pixel Aspect Ratio: Square.
6. Frame Types: Progressive Scan.
7. Audio Sample Rate: 44.1 KHz.
8. Audio Bitrate: 128 Kbps stereo.
9. Bitrate Encoding: CBR.

My file is in mp4 generated with iMovies. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use VBV by adding `-maxrate` and `-bufsize`. Use a `-maxrate` value that is below your maximum upload rate and leave some room for overhead.

Use the `-g` option for your keyframe interval with a value that is double that of your frame rate.

Make sure you're not using an ancient version of `ffmpeg` and `x264`.

Sore more details at [FFmpeg Wiki: Encoding for Streaming Sites](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites).

Answer (score 1):

These look like the specs for the Facebook Live API.

Doubtful that the random lags and pauses are on your end (or at least not in the encoding), but do check your network connection to ensure you have an excessive amount of bandwidth and relatively low latency.  Facebook Live operates with low latency, requiring your connection to be truly flawless.